# mod_rewrite append string to query

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to transform this URL:

```
http://localhost/?q=foo&s=search
```

on this:

```
http://localhost/?q=+foo&s=search (i add a plus sign before the user query)
```

I tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?q=\+%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this generates:

```
http://localhost/?q=+++++++++++++++++++++foo
```

Any advice on how to add the plus sign before the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick/easy options:

1. Add the `+` in the backend (PHP: `$query = '+' . $_GET['q'];`)
2. Add a param indicating the redirect and avoiding the redirect.

   ```
   # The example is untested, but the idea is to add an extra 
   # query parameter (rw=1). When the redirect comes back through, 
   # the redirect is not applied, as the '+' as already been 
   # put on the beginning.

   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&rw=1$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?q=\+%1&rw=1 [R=301,L,NE]
   ```

Comment: Thanks @clmarquart it works. The trick was to apply the rw=1 to avoid the redirect loop? By the way, why the loop was hapenning?

Comment: The loop happens because the redirect performs a completely new HTTP request, which comes through Apache all over again.  This causes the redirect to happen again, then again.  In this case the new query parameter is just needed so you can check against it with a RewriteCond to make sure it hasn't happened already.

Comment: Excuse me for bother you again but i have a new issue. My search page has a plugin to generates pagination of the results, like: `<prev 1 2 3 next>`. Every number has a link to a page who preserves the query and append an `?pg=#` parameter. The problem is that every time the user press a number link a new one plus sign it's added. So if you press the links 1 and next 2 and next 3 you get a query with three '+++': `http://localhost/?q=+++foo&s=search?pg=4`. How can i set the rule to avoid adding plus signs every time?

Comment: Try adding: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !q=\+`  That should cause it the RewriteRule to not match once the `+` was added.  Actually, if that condition works, you can probably get rid of the `rw=1` altogether.